# Initialize enum from associated value

Tags: kotlin, enums

I would like to initialize enum by its associated value.

My enum:

```
enum class DirectionSwiped(raw: Int){
    LEFT(4),
    RIGHT(8);
}
```

I would like to initialize it as such:

```
val direction = DirectionSwiped(raw: 4)
```

But I get this error:

> Enum type cannot be instantiated

Why is this happening? In Swift, this functionality works like this:

```
enum Direction: Int {
    case right = 2
}

let direction = Direction(rawValue: 2)
```

How can I make it work in Kotlin?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes you can

```
enum class DirectionSwiped(val raw: Int){
    LEFT(4),
    RIGHT(8);
}

val left = DirectionSwiped.LEFT
val right = DirectionSwiped.RIGHT

val leftRaw = DirectionSwiped.LEFT.raw
val rightRaw = DirectionSwiped.LEFT.raw

val fromRaw = DirectionSwiped.values().firstOrNull { it.raw == 5 }
```

This would be the correct way to access the instances of the `enum class`

What you are trying to do is create a new instance outside the definition site, which is not possible for `enum` or `sealed` classes, that's why the error says the constructor is **private**

Comment: This obviously works, but the question was about getting the enum-value by a raw value, and not getting the raw value if you already have your enum-value...

Comment: @Tagas I mention that too (i.e `fromRaw`), your answer mislead because it can and will fail

Comment: I don't see your problem... your `DirectionSwiped.values().firstOrNull { it.raw == 5 }` returns exactly the same type as my `ofRaw` function: `DirectionSwiped?`

Comment: @Tagas But I'm making it explicit by using `firstOrNull`, at a glance you see what it's doing, in your case no

Comment: There will be a compiler warning, I don't know how you can be more explicit than that...Anyhow, let's not add more useless discussion, this isn't going anywhere.

Comment: @Tagas You're right, this is pointless, btw you don't see compiler warning when you are reading code in github, also public functions like your `toRaw` should specify the return type explicitly for the same reason (and you don't do it, thats why is hard to now that your function returns nullable)

Comment: Fair enough, let me adjust that :)

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you cannot instantiate enums in Kotlin. A possible workaround would be to use a map and 2 helper methods to get enum values from raw values and vice versa:

```
enum class DirectionSwiped {
    LEFT,
    RIGHT;

    fun toRaw() = enumToRaw[this]
    companion object {
        val rawToEnum = mapOf(
                4 to LEFT,
                8 to RIGHT
        )
        val enumToRaw = rawToEnum.entries.associate{(k,v)-> v to k}
        fun ofRaw(raw: Int): DirectionSwiped? = rawToEnum[raw]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
val direction = DirectionSwiped.ofRaw(4) // LEFT
val raw = DirectionSwiped.LEFT.toRaw() // 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seems stupid to me that a language as modern as Kotlin, we can not do that like swift!

Comment: Not safe at all, `DirectionSwiped.ofRaw(5)` returns `null`, potentially creating crashes at runtime

Comment: @OmarMainegra it returns a value of type `DirectionSwiped?` - note the `?`. So yes, sure it can return null, what else would it return when there is no match? But thanks to Kotlin's nullable types, this is indeed save.

Comment: @Tagas And you are planning to do this for all enums you define?? also there is no need to define a `Map` for this `DirectionSwiped.values().firstOrNull { it.raw == 5 }`  is enough

Comment: @OmarMainegra It depends on how many enum-values there are. If it's only a couple, then sure, your solution is perfectly fine. If there are many values and accesses though, a map will be a lot more performant.

Comment: @Tagas, you are missing the point of using enum, they are supposed to be coproduct types, the same with sealed class, a closed type hierarchy to get help from the compiler (i.e. `when` statement)  thats why this is dangerous, don't use enums then

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic solution. You can add cases you want the `fun instance(raw:)` remains workable without more writing that adding cases.

```
enum class DirectionSwiped(val raw: Int){
    LEFT(4),
    RIGHT(8);
    companion object {
        fun instance(raw: Int): DirectionSwiped? {
            return values().firstOrNull { it.raw == raw }
        }
    }
}

val direction = DirectionSwiped.instance(4)
println(direction?.raw ?: "null")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate Swift's syntax by overloading `DirectionSwiped()`:

```kotlin
enum class DirectionSwiped(private val raw: Int) {
    LEFT(4),
    RIGHT(8);
    
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(raw: Int): DirectionSwiped? = 
            DirectionSwiped.values().firstOrNull { it.raw == raw }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
val direction = DirectionSwiped(raw = 4)
```

You can experiment with the above in [this Kotlin playground script](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS44LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZW51bSBjbGFzcyBEaXJlY3Rpb25Td2lwZWQocHJpdmF0ZSB2YWwgcmF3OiBJbnQpIHtcbiAgICBMRUZUKDQpLFxuICAgIFJJR0hUKDgpO1xuICAgIFxuICAgIFxuICAgIGNvbXBhbmlvbiBvYmplY3Qge1xuICAgICAgICBvcGVyYXRvciBmdW4gaW52b2tlKHJhdzogSW50KTogRGlyZWN0aW9uU3dpcGVkPyA9IFxuICAgICAgICAgICAgRGlyZWN0aW9uU3dpcGVkLnZhbHVlcygpLmZpcnN0T3JOdWxsIHsgaXQucmF3ID09IHJhdyB9XG4gICAgfVxufVxuXG52YWwgZGlyZWN0aW9uID0gRGlyZWN0aW9uU3dpcGVkKHJhdyA9IDQpXG4ifQ==).

However, **I would advise against this solution**, since it's likely to surprise readers.

A **less surprising and therefore better** variant would be:

```kotlin
enum class DirectionSwiped(private val raw: Int) {
    LEFT(4),
    RIGHT(8);
    
    
    companion object {
        fun byRaw(raw: Int): DirectionSwiped? = 
            DirectionSwiped.values().firstOrNull { it.raw == raw }
    }
}

val direction = DirectionSwiped.byRaw(4)
```